# Retrieve Back the Original Bits after a Bitshift and an OR operation

Tags: c

I have 2 routine where one sends the encrypted data and other decrypts it. I am not sure the right way of parsing the encrypted fields.

```
void send_the_encrypt_code ( UINT32 field, UINT32 index )
{
   UINT32 encrypt_code = ( field << 5 | index );
   pass_the_encrypt_code ( encrypt_code );
}

void pass_the_encrypt_code ( UINT32 encrypt_code )
{
  UINT32 field ;
  UINT32 index;

 /* How do I parse the field and index values from the encrypt_code and assign to the local variables field and index in this routine */??

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do an OR? shouldn't it be an XOR?

Comment: Hi Alex. It should be an OR operation

Comment: Mmm, I'm not sure the operation can be reversed... Where did you get the idea to encrypt this way? (perhaps I will be able to understand it better)

Comment: This is just a proposed Way of encrypting the data locally in our testing. Is there any better way of implementing the above encrypted data, so that decrypting back to fields would be an easy way ?

Comment: Is `send_the_encrypt_code()` correct and are you asking how invert it (which is not possible in general)? Or are we supposed to invent another, invertible, `send_the_encrypt_code()`?

Comment: Yes please . If send_the_encrypt_code doesn't work may be a invent a new simple one to encrypt 2 fields and decrypt them back.

Comment: Suspect this is not so much as encrypting as packing a 27-bit `field` and 5-bit `index` into 32-bit `code` - and then reversing the process.  unpacking, not decrypting.

Comment: Okay. Any Idea on how to pack and unpack in a simplest way ?

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, as I said on the comments I don't think it's possible to revert that transformation...

If you only need to pack and obscure the field you can just concatenate the data and apply a simple XOR coding...

Will something like this work for you?

Note that that you cannot store the packed data in a container the same size of the original data, hence the char*.

```
char key[] = {'P','A','S','S','K','E','Y','1'};

void decrypt ( char * encrypted){
   UINT32 field, index;
   UINT32 xor_field, xor_index;

   memcpy(&xor_field,&encrypted[0],sizeof(xor_field));
   memcpy(&xor_index,&encrypted[4],sizeof(xor_index));

   memcpy(&field,&key[0],sizeof(field));
   memcpy(&index,&key[4],sizeof(index));

   field ^= xor_field;
   index ^= xor_index;
}

void encrypt ( UINT32 field, UINT32 index ){
   char encrypted[8];
   UINT32 xor_field, xor_index;

   memcpy(&xor_field,&key[0],sizeof(xor_field));
   xor_field ^= field;
   memcpy(&xor_index,&key[4],sizeof(xor_field));
   xor_index ^= index;

   memcpy(&encrypted[0],&xor_field,sizeof(xor_field));
   memcpy(&encrypted[4],&xor_index,sizeof(xor_index));

   decrypt(encrypted);
}
```